# WPF - Cancel selection of a tab in TabControl causes problems

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs, selection, tabcontrol

I have an application with some TabControl, and in a specific tab a long computation can be started. I want the user to confirm leaving the tab and aborting the computation.
So far, I created a Behavior and attached it to the tabcontrol.
(code at the end).
My problem: suppose I want to conifrm leaving tab #3.
I choose tab #2 -> confirmation dialog pops and I choose no (CanNavigateFromMe() == false), and I return to tab #3.
Again, I choose tab #2 and get same behavior.
I want to choose it for the 3rd time - now, clicking the header does not fire the CurrentChanging event!

code for the behavior:

```
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.Loaded += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(AssociatedObject_Loaded);
    }

    void AssociatedObject_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // required in order to get CurrentItemChanging
        AssociatedObject.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = true;

        AssociatedObject.Items.CurrentChanging += new CurrentChangingEventHandler(Items_CurrentChanging);
    }



    void Items_CurrentChanging(object sender, CurrentChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = ((ICollectionView)sender).CurrentItem;

        var view = item as FrameworkElement;
        if (view == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        IAllowNavigation allowNavigation = view.DataContext as IAllowNavigation;
        if ((allowNavigation != null) &&
            (allowNavigation.CanNavigateFromMe() == false))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            AssociatedObject.SelectedItem = view;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After some help from friends, I found out I needed to:
1. call Refresh() on the collection if cancelling the selection.
2. ensure the original selection is made if I decide to allow the selection (this involves user input and takes time, meanwhile ecents inside other tabs can change the selected item)

```
    void Items_CurrentChanging(object sender, CurrentChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        var newItem = AssociatedObject.SelectedItem;
        var item = ((ICollectionView)sender).CurrentItem;


        var view = item as FrameworkElement;
        if (view == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        IAllowNavigation allowNavigation = view.DataContext as IAllowNavigation;
        if ((allowNavigation != null) &&
            (allowNavigation.CanNavigateFromMe() == false))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            AssociatedObject.SelectedItem = view;

        }
        else
        {
            AssociatedObject.SelectedItem = newItem;
        }

        ((ICollectionView)sender).Refresh();

    }
```

Comment: As you point out it is important to save the selected item at the beginning of the method, because it somehow reverts to its previous value by the time you get to your else statement.

Comment: I am encountering the same issue where if you try to navigate and cancel twice, it won't work the third time.  Calling refresh does not resolve the problem.